# What is the lead synth in Lizardking's remake of Claustrophobia?

Tags: synthesizer, replication

Can anyone hear what synth was used for the lead starting at 1.17 in this video? Is it a preset?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a Korg Wavestation lead with flanger, I'm guessing Spank-a-lead from ROM 5.